# MindMup editor - how to add a class to selected string

Tags: javascript, php, html, mindmap

I have just discovered MindMup and I need to add a way to apply a class to a span tag the same way it is shown how to change the font or the background color for examples.

```
<a data-edit="fontName 'Arial Black'"> produces <font face="Arial Black">string</font>
<a data-edit="backColor #xxx"> produces <span style="background-color: rgb(x,x,x);">string</span>
```

I tried `<a data-edit="class myclass">` to get `<span class="myclass">string</span>` but it does not work!

Where do I learn how to do that?

Comment: _Where do I learn how to do that?_ Sounds like a request to off-site-resources, which is off topic ;)

Comment: I am not asking for off-site-resources, I am asking if there is anything I missed in the MindMup editor files to understand how to do such things... I looked at the js code but could not figure out it by myself... so why I am here to ask for help.